Organize the terraform module in folders
I have following terraform code in single main.tf file
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "tfdev"
}

module "key_pair" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/key-pair/aws"

  key_name           = "web-server-key-pair"
  create_private_key = true
}


module "ec2_cluster" {
  source                 = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version                = "~> 2.0"

  name                   = "web-server"
  instance_count         = 2

  ami                    = "ami-051f8a213df8bc089"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = module.key_pair.key_pair_name
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0d311e77516a0a090"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-05308e327d3f06d8f"

  user_data = <<-EOT
    #!/bin/bash
    # Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)
    # install httpd (Linux 2 version)
    yum update -y
    yum install -y httpd
    systemctl start httpd
    systemctl enable httpd
    echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
  EOT

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}


How can I organize this into 2 separate folders. ec2/main.tf and key-pair/main.tf and have main.tf in the root folder to connect all the pieces. I should pass key_name to the ec2_cluster from the key_pair module.
ec2/main.tf should contain.
module "ec2_cluster" {
  source                 = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version                = "~> 2.0"

  name                   = "web-server"
  instance_count         = 2

  ami                    = "ami-051f8a213df8bc089"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = module.key_pair.key_pair_name
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0d311e77516a0a090"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-05308e327d3f06d8f"

  user_data = <<-EOT
    #!/bin/bash
    # Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)
    # install httpd (Linux 2 version)
    yum update -y
    yum install -y httpd
    systemctl start httpd
    systemctl enable httpd
    echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
  EOT

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

and key-pair/main.tf should contain
module "key_pair" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/key-pair/aws"

  key_name           = "web-server-key-pair"
  create_private_key = true
}


It is generally discouraged to organize a Terraform module with only a single block (other than variable declarations).

@MatthewSchuchard, what do you suggest, how should I organize the code, given that I will be adding aws-vpc module, alb module etc.

I would just split it into files in the same folder: ec2.tf and keys.tf

What you are trying here is actually to call modules from modules, i.e, that would be nested modules. Since those external modules you are using already define outputs, you can use them to pass between two different module calls in the root module. For example:
# key-pair/outputs.tf
output "key_pair_name" {
  description = "SSH key pair to use."
  value       = module.key_pair.key_pair_name
}

You would also have to define a variable in the ec2 module:
# ec2/variables.tf
variable "key_name" {
  type       = string
  decription = "SSH key pair to use for logging into the instance."
}

And in the ec2/main.tf:
module "ec2_cluster" {
  source                 = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version                = "~> 2.0"

  name                   = "web-server"
  instance_count         = 2

  ami                    = "ami-051f8a213df8bc089"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = var.key_name
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0d311e77516a0a090"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-05308e327d3f06d8f"

  user_data = <<-EOT
    #!/bin/bash
    # Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)
    # install httpd (Linux 2 version)
    yum update -y
    yum install -y httpd
    systemctl start httpd
    systemctl enable httpd
    echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
  EOT

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

Then, in the root module:
module "key_pair" {
  source = "./key-pair"
}

module "ec2_instance" {
  source   = "./ec2"
  key_name = module.key_pair.key_pair_name
}

However, as Matt suggest in his comment, it's not really a good idea to use modules like this, especially the nested modules. I would also suggest giving the style guide a read.
